# Receiving error "no database selected" when trying to query DB

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview

i'm a student in a vocational high school and i'm still new to programming, i have an assignment to create a application using c#, and i have  a problem in joining 3 tables to display on datagridview..
i have tried the query on mySql it works just fine, but when  i applied it in my c# line of code it didnt work it shows "no database selected", can somebody help me on this, here's my full code

```
string constring = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=root";
        MySqlConnection conDataBase = new MySqlConnection(constring);
        MySqlCommand cmdDataBase = new MySqlCommand("select book_detail.id_bookdetail, location.location_id, location.location_name, book.book_id, book.title from location inner join book_detail on location.location_id = book_detail.location_id inner join book on book_detail.book_id = book.book_id; ", conDataBase);
        try
        {
            MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter();
            sda.SelectCommand = cmdDataBase;
            DataTable dbdataset = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dbdataset);
            BindingSource bSource = new BindingSource();

            bSource.DataSource = dbdataset;
            transfer_view.DataSource = bSource;
            sda.Update(dbdataset);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

Comment: Youy also need to add the database name to the connection string. Check out [connection-strings.com](https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/) for more information. Great looking code, by the way - absolutely top-notch for a beginner. Keep up the good work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your connection string should specify a database name:

```
Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

(Port 3306 is the default MySql port)

Ref. [MySQL connection strings](https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/)

Comment: thanks...  for your help, reallly appriciate it,  :)

Answer (score 0):

Do a "use mydbname"

Perhaps it is the last optional parameter in prior string that u are not providing

Can do "select database()" to show current db in use